# How do they keep dino poo off the Gyrosphere?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

I have been seeing the previews for *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom*, there are glass spheres that I believe are called gyrospheres driving around.

If I walk around in a grass area with lots of large animals, I am going to get scat on my shoes, unless I am very careful.

How do they keep dino poo from blocking your view out of the gyrosphere?

---

*Not sure why this is getting down votes. I googled around, found [the wikia](http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/Gyrosphere) and it says the machine is running around in areas with animals. I see a couple of images of the machines in the rain and there are raindrops on the window, it looks like the forward window is the wheel. If rain drops stick, then grass and poo are going to stick as well.*

Comment: ...or just *mud*. Not sure we really need the scatalogical reference here.

Comment: One would imagine like any theme park there must be a need to repair and maintain the equipment. If you go on a safari in a jeep and it drives through mud, they'd probably just wash the jeep after you get out?

Comment: @Longshanks It's clean when it goes through the field though, I believe that is what the OP is referring too.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Got ya - Then perhaps there's some kind of [hydrophobic coating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvTkefJHfC0) ont the sphere that prevents it from picking up dirt?

Comment: RE: downvotes. Probably because people think the question isn't useful.

Comment: @Longshanks I don't think hydrophobic coating would keep glass from being smeared with feces.

Comment: ...or someone throwing up on the inside. Basically it's a really bad idea to have this thing where the dinos could use your ride as a football. I assume the question is the result of HISE's youtube vid mentioning this.

Comment: @Daniel, the question is independent. In the commercial, I saw a glass sphere rolling around in a dino enclosure, with enough traction to keep moving and somehow able to stay clean, the two points are not compatible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gyrosphere's shell is made out of [aluminium-oxynitride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxynitride), as Jimmy Fallon will explain to you (it's spelled aluminium oxinitride on the blackboard behind him).

That doesn't seem to have any special hydrophobic (water-repellent) properties. And actually, as can be seen in this clip from *Jurassic World*, they *do* get dirty.

No explanation is given for its relative cleanliness, but we can speculate that they're meant to be ridden through grass, which may not stick as much to the glass. Also, the chances of actually hitting dino poo aren't that big. After all, we don't see much (if any) dino poo while they're riding.

Additionally, it being a theme park, we can safely assume the gyrospheres are cleaned between rides.

---

The gyrosphere we see in *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom* is an old abandoned one. Why it's still in such good condition, we don't know.

> Its hydro-seal appears to be malfunctioning, though.